# sorting in xquery after an insertion

Tags: sorting, xquery

i want to sort every car by their total value atrribute in a descending order,

after sorting the data,i want to add attribute level to node Car.

but when i run my code the result is  not in descending order.

**my xml file:**

```
<Cars>
<Car TotalValue="27000">
<CarDetail Name="Peugot-206"/>
</Car>

<Car TotalValue="28000">
<CarDetail Name="Peugot-206"/>
</Car>

<Car TotalValue="30000">
<CarDetail Name="Peugot-206"/>
</Car>

<Car TotalValue="35000">
<CarDetail Name="Peugot-206"/>
</Car>

<Car TotalValue="270000">
<CarDetail Name="Peugot-206"/>
</Car>

<Car TotalValue="280000">
<CarDetail Name="Peugot-206"/>
</Car>

<Car TotalValue="300500">
<CarDetail Name="Peugot-206"/>
</Car>

<Car TotalValue="40000">
<CarDetail Name="Peugot-206"/>
</Car>

<Car TotalValue="270000">
<CarDetail Name="Peugot-206"/>
</Car>

<Car TotalValue="280000">
<CarDetail Name="Peugot-206"/>
</Car>

<Car TotalValue="3005000">
<CarDetail Name="Peugot-206"/>
</Car>

<Car TotalValue="400000">
<CarDetail Name="Peugot-206"/>
</Car>
</Cars>
```

**my code:**

```
let $sortResult := for $Car in doc('Process')//Car
                let $value:=number($Car/@TotalValue)
                order by $value descending 
               return $Car
for $sortItem at $position in $sortResult
return insert node (attribute Level {$position}) 
into $sortItem
```

**running result:**

```
<Cars>
<Car Level="12" TotalValue="27000">
 <CarDetail Name="Peugot-206"/>
</Car>

<Car Level="11" TotalValue="28000">
 <CarDetail Name="Peugot-206"/>
</Car>

<Car Level="10" TotalValue="30000">
 <CarDetail Name="Peugot-206"/>
</Car>

<Car Level="9" TotalValue="35000">
 <CarDetail Name="Peugot-206"/>
</Car>

<Car Level="6" TotalValue="270000">
  <CarDetail Name="Peugot-206"/>
</Car>

<Car Level="4" TotalValue="280000">
 <CarDetail Name="Peugot-206"/>
</Car>

<Car Level="3" TotalValue="300500">
 <CarDetail Name="Peugot-206"/>
</Car>

<Car Level="8" TotalValue="40000">
 <CarDetail Name="Peugot-206"/>
</Car>

<Car Level="7" TotalValue="270000">
  <CarDetail Name="Peugot-206"/>
</Car>

<Car Level="5" TotalValue="280000">
  <CarDetail Name="Peugot-206"/>
</Car>

<Car Level="1" TotalValue="3005000">
  <CarDetail Name="Peugot-206"/>
</Car>

<Car Level="2" TotalValue="400000">
 <CarDetail Name="Peugot-206"/>
</Car>

</Cars>
```

**what i need:**

```
<Cars>   
<Car Level="1" TotalValue="3005000">
 <CarDetail Name="Peugot-206"/>
</Car>

<Car Level="2" TotalValue="400000">
 <CarDetail Name="Peugot-206"/>
</Car>

<Car Level="3" TotalValue="300500">
 <CarDetail Name="Peugot-206"/>
</Car>

<Car Level="4" TotalValue="280000">
 <CarDetail Name="Peugot-206"/>
</Car>

<Car Level="5" TotalValue="280000">
 <CarDetail Name="Peugot-206"/>
</Car>

<Car Level="6" TotalValue="270000">
 <CarDetail Name="Peugot-206"/>
</Car>

 <Car Level="7" TotalValue="270000">
  <CarDetail Name="Peugot-206"/>
 </Car>

 <Car Level="8" TotalValue="40000">
   <CarDetail Name="Peugot-206"/>
 </Car>

 <Car Level="9" TotalValue="35000">
   <CarDetail Name="Peugot-206"/>
 </Car>

 <Car Level="10" TotalValue="30000">
   <CarDetail Name="Peugot-206"/>
 </Car>

 <Car Level="11" TotalValue="28000">
   <CarDetail Name="Peugot-206"/>
 </Car>

 <Car Level="12" TotalValue="27000">
  <CarDetail Name="Peugot-206"/>
 </Car>
 </Cars>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using XQuery Update to modify the original data. Your query should actually not return anything at all.

Use either XQuery Update's `copy` statement (which you can subsequently modify) or simply recreate the `<Car/>` nodes:

```
for $car at $position in (
  for $car in $xml//Car
  let $value := number($car/@TotalValue)
  order by $value descending
  return $car
)
return element Car {
  attribute Level { $position },
  $car/attribute(),
  $car/node()
}
```